# Drop in checkout chargebee

Tags: reactjs, chargebee

```
 <a
      className="button-checkout"
      href="javascript:void(0)"
      data-cb-type="checkout"
      data-cb-plan-id={
        props.pricingData.length > 1 &&
        props.pricingData[2].plan_id
      }
    >
      Subscribe
    </a>
```

im trying to feed in dynamic id in the dropin scripy of chargebee from my plans. As i have many plan i can not hard code it. But it doesnt pick up my id and throws a 404.

Comment: Have you added the script into the header tag?